# common validation error for all custom requests ibn laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

I made the role based laravel api by using laravel spatie only the user which has particular permission, he can only access that api. For validate the api permission I use laravel request for form and api validation. Now issue is I have multiple methods for that method validation I created different request file for particular method.

**Permission Validation Code in my Request File**

```
public function authorize(){
     if(Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('show all users')) {
       return true;
     } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

**Authorization error message return by API if user is not authorized for particular permission**

```
public function failedAuthorization() {
        $exception = new NotAuthorizedException('This action is unauthorized.', 403);

        throw $exception->redirectTo("safepage");
    }
```

Now the issue is I have many requests files as per my different methods and this `failedAuthorization` code is repeated in my all request file, is there any way to create common `failedAuthorization()` method for all requests file, because in above scenario there is code repetition in every request file.

Comment: Create a request for that acts as your base, as the function, than let all other request files extend that base request. Or use a trait.

Comment: Is that a valid, is there any other way?

Comment: Why would it not be a valid way? It's the way object oriented programming works.